# Vertically align a div in the middle of a Bootstrap 4.1 container-fluid > row > col

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to apply Bootstrap 4.1's [align-middle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/vertical-align/) to a `col` inside of a `row`. But it seems the content inside it stays aligned to the top. Here is my code:

```
<body class="d-flex">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="my-container" href="#">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col flex-grow-1">
          Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto text-right align-middle">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a snippet showing the result:

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="d-flex">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="my-container" href="#">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col flex-grow-1">
          Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto text-right align-middle">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I align the icon correctly?

Comment: Can you send your css code as well please?

Comment: @Comé there is no custom css code. It's all Bootstrap (and a Font Awesome icon). My own `my-container` class doesn't have any styling attached to it.

Comment: No problem. Please see answer below. Let me know if it worked for you or if you still need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap 4's `my-auto` class on the column. Here is the code:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="my-container" href="#">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col flex-grow-1 my-auto">
      <p>line 1</p>
      <p>line 1</p>
      <p>line 1</p>
    </div>
  <div class="col-auto text-right">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>
```

css:

```
p {
  margin: 16px;
}
```

The paragraph has a margin-bottom of `1rem`, so you can either remove the margin or just give it an overall margin like I did. This worked fine for me.

Comment: Genius :-) One note though, in your example code above yuo've added `my-auto` to the wrong `col`.

Comment: Oh, I see you want the `<i>` to be aligned. Same principle applies :) . If you don't mind, could you just give it an upvote as well please to ensure the correct answer is at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `i` with `span` and let the `span` have the `align-middle` class

Comment: Sorry @CodeRed it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 where do you want to add icon? Is it beside on of the lines or somewhere?

Comment: I want to have the icon with equal distance between top and bottom. So aligned center. But don't get to caught up on the icon. It could be some text instead. The important part is to center the content in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `row` a fixed height and then adjust your `col` line-height accordingly. Please see code below:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="my-container" href="#">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col flex-grow-1">
      Line 1<br>Line 2<br>Line 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto text-right">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

css:

```
.row {
 height: 150px;
}

.col {
 line-height: 50px;
}
```

If you have only one line in your column, you can make the line-height of the column the same as the row-height. You now have three lines so take the row-height divided by three.

Comment: @Comé the answer assumes that my row will always stay the same height. I need its height to adjust to the content.

Comment: Okay, I have got a different answer for your problem. I will create a new answer now.